# VB.NET DataGridview and Total

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, pos

I am trying to make a POS system using VB.net. I used datagridview to show the item, quantity, and amount. Everytime you click the button where the item is located, it will update in the datagridview. The third column is the amount. the total amount will show in "TOTAL". But whenever i click an item more than once, example, the amount is 50 per item and the quantity is 3, therefore it should show in TOTAL 150, but it only shows the total amount is 50.

What i expect to happen is that the multiplied amount in qty and amount will show up in TOTAL section (2x50 = 100) but what happened is (2x50 = 50)

This are the codes I used:
---------For Total-----------

```
Private Function Total_of_Products() As Double

    Dim Sum As Double = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        Sum = Sum + Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
    Next i
    Return Sum

End Function

Sub TotalProducts()

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        total.Text = (Total_of_Products().ToString("0.00"))
    End If
End Sub
```

----------For the Item------------

```
Private Sub toolbox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles toolbox.Click

    Dim CostofItem As Double = 20
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Value = "toolbox" Then
            row.Cells(1).Value = Double.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value) + 1
            row.Cells(2).Value = CostofItem * Double.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value)
            Exit Sub

        End If

    Next
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("toolbox", "1", CostofItem)
    TotalProducts()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you _Exit Sub_ inside the loop then none will call _TotalProducts()_ So the first time everything is OK because there is no line with the "toolbox" word, but the second time the loop exits before calling TotalProducts

Comment: Thank you. What can I do to fix it? If i put it after End If the button won't work  and if i put Exit Sub right after the TotalProducts, it will just create a new line. (1st click - 1 quantity, 2nd click - 3 quantity instead of two)

Comment: What happen if you call TotalProducts() just before exit sub

Comment: When i first put it before exit sub and deleted the one before end sub, the button will only work if you clicked it twice but when I also put it before exit sub and also at end sub it worked! Thank you so much! Did not cross my mind to also put it before exit sub

Comment: Life gets a lot easier if you put all your data in a datatable, bind the grid to the datatable and tell the table to add up the total by adding anotehr column with an Expression set to `sum(quantity * price)`. The entire thing can be done in maybe 3 lines of code